# Android db synchornizing with server

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

One of the functionalities of my app:

- download objects from server db as JSON
- parse to `MyObjects`
- if `MyObject` does not exist in client db insert
- if the `MyObject` exists in client db update
- delete all `MyObjects` from client db that are not in JSON

At first my approach was to have independent `_id` column (`PRIMARY KEY`) and store the server id in `remote_id` column. But after a while I've abandoned that idea for two reasons:

- it was a bit 'ugly' to have an `_id` column but actually use the `remote_id` most of the time (`CREATE`, `UPDATE`,`DELETE`) and use `_id` only in queries
- the debugging was a bit painful and sometimes confusing

So, I ended up with deleting the `remote_id` column and filling the `_id` with server-side `id`

That worked fine, but now it turns out I have to add a functionality to add,update and delete  `MyObject` locally. My main concern is that locally added `_id` could collide with remote `_id` value.

I came up with two solutions:

- create a composite primary key containing `_id` column with auto increment and for example `local` column with 0 or 1 value
- create another table that will contain only locally added `MyObject` instances

Which option do you consider better ? Or maybe you have other-better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have client temp table for local changes. Once client go live - you put everything from local temp to remote table and put everything from temp table to you local main table using server ids.

This way you always can find differences user did on the server side and local side.